# Can the displot function sum the values on the y-axis?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, distribution

I am using seaborn to visualize a distribution.

My data looks something like this:

```
           0        1
0      295.0  203.389
1      298.0    0.100
2      300.0    1.066
3      309.5    0.322
4      358.0   55.865
```

The 0 column is supposed to be the x-axis.

```
sns.displot(df, x=0)
```

If I run this I get a distribution that only counts the occurrences of the values. I want to use the values in the 1 column as a weight for the values in the x-axis.

Comment: can you provide a mockup of the output?

Comment: Have you tried the `weights` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `sns.kdeplot`, or similarly

```
sns.kdeplot(data = df, x = 0)
```

EDIT: or similarly `sns.displot(data = df, x = 0, kind = 'kde')`

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it is correct. kde doesn't sum/weight the values, it only counts them, but it ouputs in terms of density. Maybe I need to use barplot.

Comment: Yes it does interpret it as a continuous distribution